# How can I set uitextview size from the attributed HTML string?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am just developing and application just like news feeding. Some of the cell view I have to set `NSAttributedString` to textview and get the exact height of textview.

In my `NSAttributedString` there is HTML content. I have to set in textview because its takes too much time in web view.

The problem is that some of the time I get the perfect height of of textview and some of the time I'm not getting the height of textview. Because of`NSAttributedString` some time it considers font height and some time it is not considering it a font height.

You can get more idea if you see my code about what I have done. `templbl2` is a `UITextview` `temptext2` is `UIView`.

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: Frank-regular; font-size: 13\">%@</span>", strTerms];
            NSAttributedString * attrStr2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[str3 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Frank-regular" size:13.0]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
            templbl2.attributedText = attrStr2;
            [templbl2 sizeToFit];
            [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:attrStr2];
}
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text
{
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; // whatever your desired width is
    CGRect paragraphRect =
    [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                       context:nil];
        temptext2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, paragraphRect.size.height+60);
    return paragraphRect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: set your textview Font size 13 and Font name Frank-regular?

Comment: ya i have set. i can only set before attributes string. after i can not do any thing. once i set then there is no mean of attributed string and size. because the attributed string is dynamic. what html content is there i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try below method:

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text
        {

            CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; // whatever your desired width is

            UITextView *txtView;
            txtView.attributedText = attrStr2;

            CGSize size = [tvDummyForHeightTemp sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];



            temptext2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, size.height+60);

            return size.height;
        }
```

Hope this will help:)